# Which support team in microsoft should I reach out for Windows Automation API issues?

Tags: ui-automation, uia

I tried Accessibility, but they were not able to help on the API. I am a developer and I have development related question about Windows Automation API.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Nobody helped me here, but these URLs might be helpful to somebody who might be looking for this information

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/home?forum=windowsaccessibilityandautomation

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/winuiautomation/